# Convert GPS location to fully formatted address- via button.

Tags: php, function, gps

I need to convert gps location to a formatted address and pass it into the next page of my website.below is my code. i am just not sure of what parameters to pass over. Geo-location is very new to me.

```
function initialize()

    {
    var mapProp = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(55.125287,-6.668422),//maplocation
      zoom:10,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };


    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);



    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
        {
          var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                           position.coords.longitude);//get current gps position



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            content:'You are here'//marker feedback
          });

          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
      }
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
      map.setCenter(options.position);
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var formattedAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                //pass to next page via local storage or however you wish.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you.could you help with the button side of this??

Comment: Button side of this? Do you mean passing it to the next page? Or do you mean calling this after a user has clicked a button?

Comment: once button has been clicked what code do i need to be able to pass the information into form boxes on the next page

Comment: depending on how you want to display it on the next page...

if you want to save the formatted address then just do...
    localStorage.address = formattedAddress;

if you want to save the address in parts then I would keep the address as a list of objects...
    localStorage.address = results[0];